# Не запускается MySql с ошибкой UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER@localhost

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

Традиционное `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Место на диске есть. Сервис mysqld запускается.

В логах `UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER@localhost as on SET NAMES Quit`

Что это?

Как можно увидеть, что вызывает с таким `UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER`? И как его можно поменять?

Да. И много куда заглядывал. Изначально у меня не запускался вообще *mysqld* сервер, и таблицы чинил, и права на папки ставил и процессы убивал и прочее.

**Обновление**

Проблема не ушла, но я, собственно, и не знал, что делать. Единственное место, где я вижу хоть что-то про `UKNOWN_MYSQL_USER` - это

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld -start(){
[ -x $exec ] || exit 5
# check to see if it's already running
    RESPONSE=`/usr/bin/mysqladmin --socket="$socketfile" --      user=UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER ping 2>&1`
     if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    # already running, do nothing
    action $"Starting $prog: " /bin/true
    ret=0
       elif echo "$RESPONSE" | grep -q "Access denied for user"
```

Comment: Slip в вопросе описаны две проблемы - невозможность установить соединение с сервером и попытка обращения к сервису из под UNKNOWN_MYSQL_USER. Сейчас вопрос актуален, вы до сих пор видите сообщение Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock'?

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста как запускаете MySQL, речь идет о сервере или о консольном клиенте mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так :

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p <database>
```

Также (убедиться что он работает):

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
```

Если нету файла `mysqld.sock` 
Можно выполнить следующие команды (создаем файл и даем права на папку)

```
# sudo mkfifo /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
# sudo chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Если при попытке старта он уже пишет ошибку 111

```
# mysql start
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

> То mysql start - не совсем попытка старта..

```
/etc/init.d/mysql [re]start
```

И да.. если сервер работает, адрес socket-а можно посмотреть в .cnf файле в каталоге /etc/mysql/

Вероятно, это просто расконфигурация в файле my.cnf, в `/etc/somewhere` [(Зависимости от дистрибутива Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658142/6120970).

[Тут обсуждается данная проблема](http://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=727959)